# Multiple filters on Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to filter a table using multiple filters.At any point in time I can have either have one or all filters keyed in and the list needs to return accordingly  - I have been successful when all the filters are keyed in - but when I choose any one of it the filtering fails - Please note my code so far

the filter.html file -

```
 <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]='field1Filter ' /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]='field2Filter ' /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]='field3Filter ' /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]='field4Filter ' /></td>
                </tr>   

<tr *ngFor='let acct of Accts  | acctFilter :field1Filter :field2Filter :field3Filter :field4Filter'>                                                                                                                    
                    <td>{{acct.field1}}</td>
                    <td>{{acct.field2}}</td>
                    <td>{{acct.field3}}</td>
                    <td>{{acct.field4}}</td>
                    <td>{{acct.field5}}</td>
                    <td>{{acct.field6}}</td>
                    <td>{{acct.field7| date}}</td>
                    <td>{{acct.field8| date}}</td>
```

In my filter.pipe.ts

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { IAcct } from './Acct';

@Pipe({

    name: 'acctFilter'

})
export class AcctFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: IAcct[], field1Filter : any, field2Filter : any, field3Filter : any, field4Filter : any): IAcct[] {
        field1Filter = field1Filter ? field1Filter .toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        field2Filter = field2Filter ? field2Filter .toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        field3Filter = field3Filter ? field3Filter .toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        field4Filter = field4Filter ? field4Filter .toLocaleLowerCase() : null;

        return field1Filter && field2Filter && field3Filter && field4Filter  ? value.filter((acct: IAcct) =>
            (acct.field1.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(field1Filter) !== -1)
        && (acct.field2.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(field2Filter ) !== -1) && (acct.field3.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(field3Filter ) !== -1) &&  (acct.field4.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(field4Filter  ) !== -1)) : value;             
    }                           
}
```

If i try to use the || on any one of the above clause then it will choose only one of it obvisouly , but I would like the ability filter on any or all of the above filters.

Please let me know your inputs.

Thanks much!
S

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: The above code works when I have all the filters keyed in - but if I choose to filter lets say on any three of them.. then nothing happens on the screen no filtering happens - the whole list is as is.

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: There are no errors - its just that no filtering happens, if I dont choose all of the 4 .

Comment: You could try to add a `console.log()` like shown in my updated answer

Comment: var result =  field1Filter || field2Filter || field3Filter || field4Filter  ? value.filter((acct: IAcct) =>
        (acct.field1.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(field1Filter) !== -1)
    || (acct.field2.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(field2Filter ) !== -1) || (acct.field3.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(field3Filter ) !== -1) ||  (acct.field4.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(field4Filter  ) !== -1)) : value; But this did not work as well.. it jsut filters on one of the columns and stops there .. does not take in any of the other filters.. because of || condition